# What is the origin of the charge that Romantic literature is escapist?

Tags: history-of-literature

It is somewhat of a cliché that Romantic literature is escapist or at least tends to be escapist. Here is an example:

> The study and understanding of reasons and nature of the presence of this tendency of Escapism in English Romanticism becomes necessary in order to interpret, analyze, understand its usefulness and limitations and enjoy the works of great Literature. (mkatiyar: [Escapism in English Poetic Romanticism](https://www.wattpad.com/59756128-escapism-in-english-poetic-romanticism), published on Wattpad)

However, the terms "escapist" or "escapism" are not used in the Wikipedia articles [Romantic literature in English](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Romantic_literature_in_English&oldid=965805130), [Romantic poetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Romantic_poetry&oldid=973361738) or [English Romantic sonnets](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=English_Romantic_sonnets&oldid=931480460). The article [Romanticism](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Romanticism&oldid=975905062) states (emphasis added),

> In contrast to the Rationalism and Classicism of the Enlightenment, Romanticism revived medievalism and elements of art and narrative perceived as authentically medieval in an **attempt to escape population growth, early urban sprawl, and industrialism**.

What these articles and several [sources on Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=romantic+literature+escapism&tbm=bks&ei=PXFSX-LhPOGN1fAP6qSn2Ac&start=10&sa=N&ved=0ahUKEwii9MDD-8_rAhXhRhUIHWrSCXsQ8NMDCJMB&biw=1920&bih=880&dpr=1) do not explain is where this characterisation comes from. For example, in the case of the English Romantics, did this characterisation come from contemporaries of Wordsworth, Coleridge, Byron, Keats and Shelley, or did it emerge later, for example, at the rise of Realism? Which critic or critics first described Romanticism as escapist (in a negative way)?